# Conditional Expectation Decomposition in Regression Analysis

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis

I am currently working on my understanding of regression fundamentals and I checked [this source](http://econ.lse.ac.uk/staff/spischke/mhe/ex_ch3.pdf) (one can find the (even exact) same statement in multiple sources).
In *Theorem 3.1.1*, the author claims to prove the so called *Conditional Expectation Function  (CEF) Decomposition property*, which states:

**Theorem 3.1.1:**

We have

$$Y_i=E(Y_i|X_i)+\epsilon_i$$

with the property that $(a)$ $E(\epsilon_i|X_i)=0$ and $(b)$ $E(f(X_i)\epsilon_i)=0$ for any function $f$.

The problem is, the proof only checks $(a)$ and $(b)$ but never checks the actual existence of the decomposition of $Y_i=E(Y_i|X_i)+\epsilon_i$.

The author then claims that

> This theorem says that any random variable,
>   $Y_i$
>   , can be decomposed into a piece that's "explained by
>   $X_i$", i.e., the CEF, and a piece left over which is orthogonal to (i.e., uncorrelated with) any function of $X_i$
>   .

Do we have to prove this or comes this as some sort of assumption (couldn't find it, but surely one could just build the model like this) or is this a result from somewhere else, like factorization lemma or so? 
The whole thing sounds a bit sloppy, clearly things like measurability are dropped, but still, what do I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the equality 
$$
Y_i=\mathbb E\left[Y_i\mid X_i\right]+Y_i-\mathbb E\left[Y_i\mid X_i\right];
$$
defining $\varepsilon_i:=Y_i-\mathbb E\left[Y_i\mid X_i\right]$ gives that 
$\mathbb E\left[\varepsilon_i\mid X_i\right]=0$, from which $\mathbb E\left[f\left(X_i\right)\varepsilon_i\right]=0$ follows.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I was able to follow the proof for $(a/b)$ (even without knowing this decomposition exists) but somehow missed this idea, thanks!